# Regex Word Boundary, Pattern.quote and Parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a function that allows users to search a field of text for search terms that they can enter, and mark them up in some way such as highlighting.  What I currently have is:

```
String text = "This is my (simple) test.";
String searchExpression = "(?i)\\b(" + Pattern.quote(searchTerm) + ")\\b";
String replaceExpression = markupToken + "$1" + markupToken;
String newText = text.replaceAll(searchExpression, replaceExpression);
```

This works great if search term is "simple"; however, if the user searches for "(simple)" it will not successfully match.  If I remove Pattern.quote or the \b's this works fine.

Is there a way to modify the searchExpression that it will work in both of these scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your regex is failing because you cannot match `\b` (word boundary) before and and after `(` and `)` since these are not considered word characters.

You can tweak your regex as this:

```
String searchExpression = "(?i)(?<!\\w(?=\\w))(" + Pattern.quote(searchTerm) +
                          ")(?!(?<=\\w)\\w)";
```

i.e. use lookarounds on either side which means there should not a word character before and after the pattern if search term has a word character at start and end.

Comment: This does fix the problem I'm having, but wouldn't this potentially break in other ways though?  For example if a user searches for "/" in 1/3/14 it would not return since it is surrounded by a word character, right?

Comment: But then why do you need a word boundary? Whole purpose of word boundary is that there should not be any word characters on either side

Comment: I guess the issue I am having is I don't want to match on substrings of words.  So, I was trying to differentiate between text and special characters.  So matching on "/" in a date is okay, but I don't want to match on "his" in "this".